# UIWebView link to native controller router framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working on an app that also has a related website (essentially mirrored functionality), and I am looking at ways of introducing some HTML elements presented in a UIWebView in an existing app that could potentially have links in them.

These pages will be viewable on the web version of the app as well, and will be links to existing pages, and I need to be able to intercept the touch event and route the user to the relevant native view controller inside the app rather than triggering the page load.

I'm aware of how to do it via the delegate of the UIWebView, but I was wondering if there are some tips or even a framework someone knows of to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebView to load a html page to your app, you can link to exist page.
If you want html code to communicate with native code ,you can use three ways through js call.

One is XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xmlhttp;
function sendRequest() 
{
    xmlhttp=null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for all new browsers
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {// code for IE5 and IE6
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (xmlhttp!=null)
    {
        //url should be http://
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=state_Change;
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.baidu.com",true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
    }
}

function state_Change()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  { 
  if (xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert("status code is 200") 
    }
  else
    {
        alert("Problem retrieving XML data");
    }
  }
}
```

Another is Iframe:

```
function sendIframeRequest () {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var url= "myapp:" + "&func=iFrameCall" ;
    url = "http://www.baidu.com";
    iframe.src = url;
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iFrame);
    iframe = null;
}
```

Or use document.location

```
function sendDocumentRequest () 
{
    var url= "cpcall:" + "&class=CPCameraPlugin&parameters=camera";
    document.location = url;
}
```

On native side, there are two ways you can handle js request,One use UIWebView delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *    )request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Another you can register a NSURLProtocol, use below function to handle it:

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    //do what you want
}
```

The famous framework is cordova that a platform for building native mobile applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You can check with it, project
location is [enter link description here](http://cordova.apache.org/)